# Get User IP Address in Twig Template

Tags: theming, 8

Is there a way to get the user's IP address in a twig template? All the twig examples I find say to do it like this:

```
{% set ipAddr = app.request.server.get("REMOTE_ADDR") %}
```

But this variable always returns NULL. These examples aren't specific to Drupal so I'm guessing part of the Drupal implementation blocks/omits this.

Comment: Preprocess the template and get the IP that way?

Comment: That's exactly the solution that I ended up going with as shown below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you want to get the ip in the page.html.twig file.

in your

> YOURTHEME.theme

you can try

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;

function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['page']['ip'] = \Drupal::request()->getClientIp();

}
```

in your template

> page.html.twig

you can try:

{{ page.ip }}

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I had just found the xxx.theme file and was working on a preprocess function when I saw your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work for me because of drupal cache system...

Comment: As time has progressed I've noticed that @Sky is correct, Drupal will generate an IP the first time the template is loaded and then cache that IP. Any future users will see the cached IP instead of their own.